# Обработка условий в шаблоне после передачи данных через request.GET.get. Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Только начинаю изучать Django.Хочу, чтобы шаблон проверял положительное число или отрицательное. Соответственно есть такой код:

```
`{% if n > 0 %}
<p>Число n положительное</p>
{% else %}
<p>Число n отрицательное</p>
{% endif %}
<p>n = {{ n }}</p>`
```

Если я в функции обработчике заранее задаю переменную, то всё ок. Но если я хочу чтобы он считаывал с Get-запроса эту переменную, то условие не работает.`

```
def index(request):
    n = request.GET.get("n","")
    header = "Personal Data"                    
    langs = ["English", "German", "Spanish"]    
    user ={"name" : "Tom", "age" : 23}          
    addr = ("Абрикосовая", 23, 45)             
    data = {"header": header, "langs": langs, "user": user, "address": addr, "n" : n}
    return render(request, "firstapp/home.html", context=data)`
```

В итоге переменную считывает, выводит, но условие не проходит и пишет, что отрицательное. Что не так ?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сравнить число со строкой

Comment: А вы реально используете шаблонизатор Jinja2 с Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index(request):
    n = request.GET.get('n', '')
    if not n.isnumeric():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Параметр n должен быть числом')
    ...
    data = {..., 'n': int(n)}
    return render(request, 'firstapp/home.html', context=data)
```